# How to select the first li element in selenium test?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

The structure of the tags is shown in the screenshot

[image]

I am trying to use this python code to access the first `li` element:

```
invitations = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('members-holder li#invitation-holder > :first-child')
```

`elem` is a very top level element that contains all the tags

I got this exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"members-holder li#invitation-holder > :first-child"}
```

I have tried a few variation but cannot get the result I want. What is the best way to select the said element?

**EDIT**

I have tried an alternative css selector `.members-holder .invitation-holder:first-child` in developer console in chrome and it works. But when I plug it in the python selenium code, the same exception is thrown.

Comment: i think it is el.find , not elem.find

Comment: Is it under any frame/iframe? or does it take time to load ?

Comment: @VivekSingh You have a very good point! It is hidden at the very beginning

Comment: Then you can use wait condition for visibility. Happy to help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should fix your CSS selector:

```
.members-holder ul li.invitation-holder
```

And, since you need the first `li`, just use the [`find_element_by_css_selector()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.members-holder ul li.invitation-holder')
```

Aside from that, you may need to e[xplicitly wait for the element to become visible](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".members-holder ul li.invitation-holder"))
)
```

If you would still get an exception trying to reach the element, check if an element is inside an `iframe` - if yes, switch to it first:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('frame_id')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

# find the element
```

Comment: the `switch_to.frame('id')` hint was especially useful!

Answer (score 3):

Try to identify element using this way.

```
WebElement parentDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("'members-holder"));
```

now Do

```
WebElement ul = parentDiv.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

First element is

```
lis.get(0);
```

This is java code. You can workout equilent in python.
Hope it helps.

Comment: How's `WebElement ul = parentDiv.findElements(By.tagName("ul"));` returns the a SINGLE element? It should return a list